# Подскажите, как по клику на кнопку сделать p или span редактируемыми? React

Tags: reactjs

Создал элементу p, следующим образом тег для редактирования `contenteditable={String(el.edit)}` всё работает, однако реакт ругается `index.js:1375 Warning: Invalid DOM property contenteditable.` Поэтому подскажите пожалуйста каким простым способом можно реализовать возможность редактирования по клику для P или span?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить рядом след. тег `suppressContentEditableWarning={true}` это убирает ошибку